# there is some bug in the androidbox firmwere,andbox rockchip rk3228a,in this bug there is a alert dialog box is open when we restart the android box?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, firmware

I Have a android box in which I run my tv Appliction that are live running but there is some bug in the androidbox firmwere, model number of andbox is rockchip rk3228a,in this bug there is a alert dialog box is open when we restart the android box? there is no bug in our app for information.
when we restart the android box the alert dialog is popup, this Alert dialog is action required dialog which has a option bluetooth and package manager but when we click to complete the action we are getting the package parsing error but when we just normal click on screen from remote the alert dialog is disappear but after sometime it appear again, what to do remove this issue programatically?

I try the overlay Permission,performclickevent, install the same package application, request focus,disable all the permission of of system app, no thirdParty app installed,broadcastReciever.

I want to remove the alertDialog programatically or hand using some apps.
**Model no. of Android box: RockChip rk3228A**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.